# How to make a CAD/CAM Softwares like AutoCad - SolidWorks

Tags: 3d, cad, solidworks, catia

I know its not something you do alone and in a day but I ve been just curious what do I need know what mentioned quests above.
I ve been searching through web a little I ve seen Open Cascade but it seems like not used widely...
Which "Geometric Kernel" is best for it if it exists (I maybe misunderstand term of Geometric Kernel)
I need books or video tutorials, thanks in advance (I know some C++ and QT is deffinetly not an answer)

Comment: I assume you looked at FreeCad? https://github.com/FreeCAD/FreeCAD

Comment: Later on I found out Vulkan can be useful will try in some free time

Comment: @Kerim Could you please remove the [ansys] tag since this is a CAD and not a FEA question.